# Being a new user facing Login problem

Tags: login

I'm new to ubuntu. When I installed the Ubuntu 13.10 by installing wubi.exe, I was asked to reboot. The reboot was successful, being totally new to the UI I was amazed but when the log on screen popped out, I was surprised as I'm not having anything(no username, no password) and it is asking for the username and password .

Please help me.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you mean you don't know the user name and password and can't log in? Do you mean the computer boots into Ubuntu but does not ask for user name and password? Do you mean the computer does not boot properly and does not ask for user name and password? **Please edit your original question above** and add more information.

Comment: its asking for the username and password which I dont have !

Comment: Why not? When you did the Wubi install it asked you to create an user name and password. Try uninstalling from within Windows (use Add/Remove Software in Windows) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost always best to install from the cd, just as it is less of a "port" or the installer. You need to create a username and password to install, those are your login credentials.

Comment: its not asking to create any of that, but it just asks for entering the username and password

Comment: try installing from the dvd/cd: wubi is not a great way to do it, they only really have that for netbooks that don't have disk drives

Comment: plus a livecd is basically as useful as a boot disk can be, everything is on it, and fully functional in a complete gui environment.